# How to take network snaphot in Caffe on demand?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I want to be able to take network snapshot on-demand (say on some condition) as the training is going on. Is there a way to do this with Caffe?

Comment: you can do it if you train in python

Comment: Can you provide more details on how this can be done in python then?

Answer (score 1):

For example with callbacks in Python:

```py
import caffe

def OnStart():
  pass # both callbacks must be defined anyway 

def OnGradientsReady():
  global solver
  if solver.iter == 17:
    solver.snapshot()

solver = caffe.get_solver("mnist/lenet_solver_t1.prototxt")
solver.add_callback(OnStart, OnGradientsReady)
solver.solve()
```